# StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: No connection (requires writable - not eligible for replica)

Tags: docker, .net-core, redis, digital-ocean, stackexchange.redis

I have used `Redis` `version 2.6.66` and `DotNet Core 6.0` in my project.
The prject works well in the local but after deploying it on [cloud.digitalocean.com](https://cloud.digitalocean.com/)
I get an error.

How Can I solve it?

Error:

> fail: API.Middleware.ExceptionMiddleware[0] No connection (requires
> writable - not eligible for replica) is active/available to service
> this operation: SETEX /api/products|pageIndex-1|pageSize-6|sort-name,
> mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 >
> StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: No connection (requires
> writable - not eligible for replica) is active/available to service
> this operation: SETEX /api/products|pageIndex-1|p> at
> StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ThrowFailed[T](TaskCompletionSource`1
> source, Exception unthrownException) in
> /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 1836
> --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Infrastructure.Services.ResponseCacheService.CacheResponseAsync(String
> cacheKey, Object response, TimeSpan timeToLive) in
> C:\Workspace\MainProjects\eshop\sigma-backend-dotnet\sigma> at
> API.Helpers.CachedAttribute.OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext
> context, ActionExecutionDelegate next) in
> C:\Workspace\MainProjects\eshop\sigma-backend-dotnet\sigma\API\He> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope,> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
> context) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Obje> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boo> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker
> invoker) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker
> invoker) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context) at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext) at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider) at
> API.Middleware.ExceptionMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) in
> C:\Workspace\MainProjects\eshop\sigma-backend-dotnet\sigma\API\Middleware\ExceptionMiddleware.cs:line
> 47

[image: error]

docker-compose configuration:

```
services:

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data

  redis-commander:
    image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOSTS=local:redis:6379
      - HTTP_USER=XXX
      - HTTP_PASSWORD=YYY
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    depends_on:
      - redis

    
volumes:
  redis-data:
```

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(c =>
{
    var configuration = ConfigurationOptions.Parse(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Redis"), true);
    return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configuration);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deployed the project according to the instructions below:

## Deploy to Linux using `Docker` - for use with `.Net 6.0`

1. Create a new droplet with `Digital Ocean` using the `Docker 19.03.12` on `Ubuntu 20.04`

IP address: Your IP address

Password for root user: YourPassword

2. Login to the droplet using either the terminal or Powershell:

   ssh root@ipaddress

You will be asked for your password.   Enter this.

3. Create a new docker-compose file using the following command:

   sudo nano docker-compose.yml
4. Copy and paste in the docker-compose configuration:

[image: docker-compose]

5. Run the following command to start the docker services

   docker-compose up -d
6. Install and configure apache by running the following commands:

   sudo apt update

   sudo apt install apache2

   a2enmod proxy proxy_http proxy_html rewrite

   systemctl restart apache2

   sudo ufw app list

   sudo ufw allow 'Apache Full'

   sudo systemctl status apache2
7. Optional - allow the ports through the firewall to allow you to manage PostGreSQL and Redis via the ports.

```
sudo ufw allow 8080/tcp

sudo ufw allow 8081/tcp
```

8. Test you can access the default apache page by browsing to:  http://ipaddress
9. Create a new directory that will contain our published dotnet app and assign rights to the user:

   sudo mkdir /var/skinet

   sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/skinet
10. Create a new config file for the skinet app:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/skinet.conf
```

11. Paste in the following configuration which will set up a reverse proxy with the Kestrel server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

12. Enable the skinet site by running the following commands:

```
a2ensite skinet

ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

a2dissite 000-default

systemctl reload apache2
```

13. Install the deploy reloaded extension.   Create a settings.json file in the .vscode directory and update the IP address and password for your server:

```
{
    "deploy.reloaded": {
        "packages": [
            {
                "name": "Version 1.0.0",
                "description": "Package version 1.0.0",

                "files": [
                    "publish/**"
                ]
            }
        ],

        "targets": [
            {
                "type": "sftp",
                "name": "Linux",
                "description": "SFTP folder",

                "host": "ipaddress", "port": 22,
                "user": "root", "password": "your password",

                "dir": "/var/skinet",
                "mappings": {
                    "publish/**": "/"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

14. Optional - Change the logging level for the appsettings.json to information for the Microsoft logging level:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
}
```

15. Republish the app with changes by running the following command in VS Code terminal:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o publish skinet.sln
```

16. Deploy the files by using the `command pallette -> deploy reloaded -> deploy package`
17. Add an endpoint to stripe for to point to the IP address of the server and select the 2 events we want to listen to:  `payment_intent.succeeded`, `payment_intent.payment_failed`.  Note the web hook `MY_SECRET_PASSWORD` as we will need this soon.

```
http://ipaddress/api/payments/webhook
```

18. Back on the linux server create a service config for the kestrel server:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/skinet-web.service
```

19. Update the configuration for your API keys where it says REPLACEME and then paste the config into the nano editor

```
[Unit]
Description=Kestrel service running on Ubuntu 20.04
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/skinet
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/skinet/API.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=skinet
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment='Token__Key=CHANGE ME TO SOMETHING SECURE'
Environment='Token__Issuer=http://REPLACEME'
Environment='StripeSettings__PublishibleKey=REPLACEME'
Environment='StripeSettings__SecretKey=REPLACEME'
Environment='StripeSettings__WhSecret=REPLACEME'
Environment='ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=appuser;Password=MY_SECRET_PASSWORD; Database=skinet'
Environment='ConnectionStrings__IdentityConnection=Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=appuser;Password=MY_SECRET_PASSWORD; Database=identity'
Environment='ConnectionStrings__Redis=localhost'
Environment='ApiUrl=http://ipaddress/Content/'
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

20. Install the .Net runtime using the instructions here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2004-
21. Restart the journal service by running the following command:

```
systemctl restart systemd-journald
```

22. Start the kestrel service by running the following command:

```
sudo systemctl start skinet-web.service
```

23. Check it is started by running:

```
netstat -ntpl
```

24. Check the journal by running:

```
journalctl -u skinet-web.service --since "5 min ago"
```

25. Make sure there are no errors and then test you can browse to the published app on http://ipaddress